# How get a High Performance UIWebView -> UIImage on ipad retina?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, retina-display

Have page flip type application that needs to convert the contents of a fullscreen UIWebView to a UIImage very quickly (e.g. 200ms tops).  Sacrificing quality for speed is OK.  Having a real tough time getting anywhere near this on a iPad3 retina.

Do create a UIImage i am doing the common renderInContext method:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, YES, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[view.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

On a ipad3 retina display I typically see 400-500ms.  Interestingly the second time the method is run it is much quicker (around 100ms), which doesn't help but suggests some sort of caching is happening.

I have tried the following things:

1. I have tried playing with the scale and opaque parameters UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions to ever possible combination.  Setting the scale to say .5 or 1.0 actually makes it even slower.
2. Adding CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationNone). No change to performance.
3. webview.shouldRasterize=YES.  No change to performance.
4. Shrinking the UIWebView in half and then scaling to fullscreen .  This does help but is still around 300ms.

Any other ideas? Running this on a ipad1-2 is ok - but the ipad3 retina just kills the performance.

Comment: You mention the iPad 1 and 2 but don't specify if your testing is on the iPad 3 or 4. Are there differences between the 3 and 4?

Comment: Testing on ipad3.  Don't have an ipad4.  Thanks will update the question

Comment: the iPad 3 graphics performance is very underpowered for the number of pixels in the retina display. I bet you wouldn't have an issue on the iPad 4, would be interesting to know.